# How to create auto incrementing table based on a column name?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, statistics, method-call

The title might be a little confusing but I will try explaining here better.

What I want to achieve is:

1. Create a table with 3 columns (so far so good):

   ```
   CREATE TABLE StatisticCounter
   (
       statisticID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY (START with 1000 INCREMENT by 1), 
       statistikname varchar(255),
       counter integer 
   );
   ```
2. Create a way to call (function, procedure, trigger or something. I will call it function for now) that will increment `counter` with 1 based on `statistikname` or `statisticid`.

The restriction here being: said statistic is an SQL script ran through a cockpit file with a little bit of a different syntax than regular sql (in: out: select, WHERE with variables). I want to put a function or something in this cockpit file, that will run each time the script is run. Which will auto increment the number of times the statistic has been used.

I have no idea what I need (function, procedure, trigger or anything else) and this is why I am writing it a bit vague.

EDIT: I tried with merge but I always get the WHEN NOT MATCHED result executed. Without CAST its the same.

```
merge into StatisticCounter stc using 
CAST((select 1000 id from dual)AS INTEGER) val on (stc.statisticid=val.id) 
when matched then 
UPDATE StatisticCounter SET counter = counter + 1; 
when not matched then 
select * from dual;
```

Comment: Use `merge` statement to create new row for new statistic and update existing row for existing statistic. This is sometimes called as `UPSERT` in other DBMS.

Comment: I try, but I always get the WHEN NOT MATCHED result executed. Without CAST its the same.

| merge into StatisticCounter stc
using CAST((select 1000 id from dual)AS INTEGER) val on (stc.statisticid=val.id)
when matched then 
    UPDATE StatisticCounter SET counter = counter + 1;
when not matched then 
    select * from dual;

Comment: Your statement is syntactically incorrect, so it's hard to say what is the reason

Comment: Your `when not matched` clause should contain an `insert`, not a `select`.

Comment: Thank you. i found an answer to my issue. Will post it as a comment and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on my own after going through a lot of functions and procedures.

1. Create table;
2. Create function;
3. Call function in file.

The important thing here is that the outside _cockpit file that executes the SQL goes through all OUT parameters for each line the statistic returns as result. This makes the counter go wild - no way to catch END of statistic or beginning. So I made a second _cockpit with only 1 result and attach it to the statistic I want to count.

> CREATE TABLE UDX_Table_StatisticCounter(statisticID INTEGER,
> StatistikName varchar2(256 char), counter integer);

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UDX_FUNC_StatisticCounter(datainput IN
> VARCHAR2)   RETURN VARCHAR2 IS   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
> BEGIN
> UPDATE UDX_Table_StatisticCounter SET counter = counter +1 WHERE statisticID=datainput;
> COMMIT;
> RETURN 'done';   END UDX_FUNC_StatisticCounter;